# Artificial Neural Network: Multi-Layer Perception ORDER/PROCCESS

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am currently learning pattern recognition. I have a 7 year background in programming, so, I think like a programmer.

The documentation on ANN's tell me nothing about what *order everything is processed*, or at least does not make it very clear. This is annoying as I don't know how to code the formulas.

I found a nice gif which I hope is correct. Can someone please give me a step by step process of a artificial neural network back propagation with for example 2 inputs, 1 hidden layer with 3 nodes, 2 outputs using the sigmoid.

Here is the [gif](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~cs9417ml/MLP2/MainPage.gif).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113497/backpropagation-algorithm-implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Emile said you go layer by layer from input to output and then you propagate error backwards again layer by layer.

From what you have said I expect that you are trying to make "object oriented" implementation where every neuron is object. But that is not exactly the fastest nor easiest way. The most usual implementation is done by Matrix operations where 
every layer is described by single Matrix (every row contains weights of one neuron plus threshold)

this is matlab code should do the trick:

```
output_hidden = logsig( hidden_layer * [inputs ; 1] );
```

`inputs` is column vector of inputs to layer

`hidden_layer` is matrix of weights plus one row which describes thresholds in hidden layer

`output_hidden` is again column vector of outputs of all neurons in layer which can be used as input into next layer

`logsig` is function which do sigmoid transform on all members of vector one by one

`[inputs ; 1]` creates new vector with 1 at the end of column vector `inputs` it is here because you need "virtual input" for thresholds to be multiplied with.

if you will think about it you will see that matrix multiplication will do exactly summation over all inputs multiplied by weight to output, you will also see that it doesn't matter in what order you do all the things. in order to implement it in any other language just find yourself good linear-algebra library. Implementing back-propagation is a bit trickier and you will need to tho some matrix transpositions (e.g. flipping matrix by diagonal)

Comment: I am wanting to implement it into a Java project so I was considering a non-matlab approach!

Comment: It is not Matlab approach it is more abstract approach. I would still advice to find some linear algebra library with matrices, I've just quickly found: JAMA,  its class Matrix can do all you need, (*,transpose,...). It was first i stumbled upon so i don't know if it is good.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the gif, processing is per layer. As there are no connections within a layer, the processing order within a layer does not matter. Using the ANN (classifying) is done from input layer through hidden layers to the output layer. Training (using backpropagation) is done from output layer back to input layer.

Comment: So I first iterate through every node in every layer from input to output, then iterate back from the output layer updating weights between every layer towards the input layer?

Comment: You iterate the value only from input to output, but propagate the error you measure from output to input, adjusting the weights.